VS Code fails to update import on file change for images, not jsx
When I move around jsx files, the import of this jsx files get updated where they are called. However, when I move around my jgp/svg/png files in my assets folder, their imports do not get updated. How can I fix this issue?
I have set javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled and typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled to always, and even added a js config file as below and the issue persists.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2016",
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}

